# Is there a way to get the 'name' of the socketio background task that called a function?

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I have an application using several flask socketio background tasks. Each async task does something different, and are defined in different files. Rather than just printing everything, I'd like to start routing debug information through a writeToConsole wrapper function. It'll start by printing the current time stamp, the name or ID of the task that called the function, and then the message. Eventually, I'll have the function write to a log file, but for now this is sufficient.

If these tasks were done using the threading module, I could just call threading.current_thread().name and I'd get an identifier for each thread. However, using that here simply returns 'MainThread'. Here's an example of my current application, as well as what I'd like to do with the writeToConsole:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio= SocketIO(app)


socketio.start_background_task( myTask1 )
socketio.start_background_task( myTask2 )
socketio.start_background_task( myTask3 )


def myTask1():
     while True:
          writeToConsole("Foo")
          socketio.sleep( 1 )

def myTask2():
     while True:
          writeToConsole("Bar")
          socketio.sleep( 2 )

def myTask3():
     while True:
          writeToConsole("Baz")
          socketio.sleep( 3 )

def writeToConsole( msg ):
     name = ???
     time_stamp = "12:34:56"
     print(f"{time_stamp} - Process {name} says: {msg}")
```

Does anyone have any more information they could give me? I don't necessarily care if the identifier is 'clean' like ProcessName, or just a numerical ID -- as long as it's unique to each task, that's fine with me. I've looked through the flask_socketio.SocketIO documentation online, but I can't seem to find anything to help me out.

Worst case scenario I can add a new arg to writeToConsole and just feed it some unique identifier that I come up with manually, but that strikes me as inelegant and a bit clunky so I'd rather not if there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what concurrency library you are using. If you were using standard threads, then you could get a unique thread identifier with something like:

```
import threading
print(id(threading.get_current()))
```

If instead you are using greenlet based concurrency (gevent or eventlet), then you can do this:

```
import greenlet
print(id(greenlet.getcurrent()))
```

When using gevent or eventlet you also have the option to "monkey patch" the standard library so that it becomes non-blocking. If you do the monkey patching then the above example based on the `threading` library will also give you unique identifiers per task.